# Create array of negative numbers in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created an array of positive, negative and zero numbers but it treats all the elements in the array as positive numbers. Here in code, the positiveCount is 6. How to put negative numbers in an array in Objective-C?

```
NSInteger positiveCount = 0;
NSInteger zeroCount = 0;
NSInteger negativeCount = 0;

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@-4,@-3,@-9,@0,@4,@1, nil];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < arr.count; i++){
    NSLog(@"%d",arr[i]);
    if (arr[i] > 0)
    {
        positiveCount += 1;
    } else if (arr[i] < 0){
        negativeCount += 1;
    } else {
        zeroCount += 1;
    }
}

NSLog(@"%d",positiveCount);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements in your array are not numbers, they are `NSNumber` instances, that is, pointers. Pointers are always positive:

```
for (NSNumber* number in arr) {
    NSInteger intValue = number.integerValue;
    NSLog(@"%d", intValue);

    if (intValue > 0) {
        positiveCount += 1;
    } else if (intValue < 0) {
        negativeCount += 1;
    } else {
        zeroCount += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way for the solution using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`,

```
__block NSInteger positiveCount = 0;
__block NSInteger zeroCount = 0;
__block NSInteger negativeCount = 0;

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@-4,@-3,@-9,@0,@4,@1, nil];

[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSInteger value = ((NSNumber *)obj).integerValue;
    if (value > 0) {
        positiveCount += 1;
    } else if (value < 0) {
        negativeCount += 1;
    } else {
        zeroCount += 1;
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)positiveCount);
```